# Rust conflict with error-chain and websocket crates

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use error-chain with the websocket crate, but running into an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. [`WsUpgrade::accept`](http://cyderize.github.io/rust-websocket/doc/websocket/server/upgrade/struct.WsUpgrade.html#method.accept) has the following signature:

```
fn accept(self) -> Result<Client<S>, (S, IoError)>
```

Note that the `Err` variant is a tuple. I want to configure error-chain to handle calls to this method, so I tried to do so as follows in the relevant consuming module:

```
mod errors {
    error_chain! {
        foreign_links {
            WebSock((::std::net::TcpStream, ::std::io::Error));
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the following error, seemingly related to the presence of the tuple.

```
error: expected identifier, found `(`
  --> src/lib/websock.rs:23:21
   |
23 |             WebSock((::std::net::TcpStream, ::std::io::Error));
   |                     ^
```

How can I resolve this? Hopefully I've missed something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to introduce a type alias:

```
mod errors {
    type WebSocketError = (::std::net::TcpStream, ::std::io::Error);
    error_chain! {
        foreign_links {
            WebSock(WebSocketError);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this type does not implement traits required by error-chain (such as `Error` and `Display`), so it can't be used there.

I think the simplest solution is to convert the error manually using `Result::map_err` before passing the value to error-chain. For example, the following construction will produce `Result<Client<S>, IoError>`:

```
x.accept().map_err(|e| e.1)
```